# Expressions and for loops in C

Tags: c, loops

Is this correct way of assigning an expression to a variable?

```
int a == ( i<3 );
```

And I want to use a for loop like this

```
for(i=0;a; i++)
```

Comment: No. Use `for(i=0; i<3; i++)`.

Comment: Is there any otherway to assign an expression to a variable?

Comment: No, there is no way to assign an expression to a variable.

Comment: You would need to use a macro to do this, but it's a bad idea that will hurt readability. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: If you want to reuse a specific expression multiple times on multiple different locations in the code, you write a function wrapping the expression.

Answer (score 4):

The assignment operator is `=`. So the correct way to assign an expression to a variable is

```
int a = i < 3;
```

More accurately, this assigns the **value** of the expression to a variable. It does not assign the expression itself to the variable. This means that the expression is evaluated immediately. When you do

```
for(i=0;a; i++)
```

The value of `a` will never change even though `i` does.

The idiomatic way of writing for loops is to write the boolean expression inline:

```
for(i=0;i<3; i++)
```

If you have some more complicated calculation to determine when a loop should end, then you can write a function for the calculation. For example:

```
int condition(int i) {
    return i < 3;
}
```

Now you can write the for loop as

```
for (i = 0; condition(i); i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use macros like following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define a(i) i < 3
int main(void) {
    for(int i =0; a(i); i++) {
        printf("%d\n",i);
    }
    return 0;
}
Output
0
1
2
```

## EDIT

As others said macro is not a good idea when the condition is large. In that case you can make a separate function for the complex logic and use that in your for loop condition part. Like following:

```
int a(i) {
  return i < 3; // Your condition. It may be even more complex as per your requirement.
}
```

Then you can use that function in your for loop in the following way:

```
for(int i =0; a(i); i++ ){...}
```

Comment: No good. Need to wrap macro and use of argument in parentheses

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, why would you even want to? Can you give me an example, where this would be useful? Just curious, maybe we find better solution :)

Also, you can read more about loops at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for

Comment: Problem statement: print numbers in a square shape like this,.     9  8  7                                                                                                        -----               2  1  6                                                                        ----                3  4  5.      To implement this I need to decrease rows once and increase other time. So, I was thinking something like this.                                                
    a= (n%2==0)? i<n: i>n;
    b= (n%2==0)? i++:i-- ;

Comment: yeah, you cannot do that. Take a look at Code-Apprentice's reply, he has some good advices